# C# Add comma after every number sequence in string

Tags: c#, string

I have many strings with numbers.
I need to reformat the string to add commas after all number sequences.
Numbers may sometimes contain other characters including 12-3 or 12/4
e.g.

- "hello 1234 bye" should be "**hello 1234, bye**"
- "987 middle text 654" should be "**987, middle text 654,**"
- "1/2 is a number containing other characters" should be "**1/2, is a
  number containing other characters**"
- "this also 12-3 has numbers" should be "**this also 12-3, has
  numbers**"

Thank you all

**EDIT:**
My example does not account for any special characters. I didn't include it originally as I thought I'd get a fresh perspective if someone can do this more efficiently - my bad!

```
    private static string CommaAfterNumbers(string input)
    {
        string output = null;

        string[] splitBySpace = Regex.Split(input, " ");
        foreach (string value in splitBySpace)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                if (int.TryParse(value, out int parsed))
                {
                    output += $"{parsed},";
                }
                else
                {
                    output += $"{value} ";
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried so far?  Stackoverflow is not a code generator

Comment: please show your current attempt to solve the problem, and explain what goes wrong, then we can help you to fix it. That's how this site works. We don't just go and do all the research, coding and testing on your behalf without you being involved. We're volunteers, this is our free time we are giving to help people, so in return we expect you to have at least spent a bit of your own time trying first before asking. You can research about the various string manipulation functions, regular expressions etc quite easily online and make some attempt at it. And you also learn more that way, too.

Comment: you can use regex to do this

Comment: Even pseudo code is a start.

Comment: edited to include attempt

Comment: @monstertjie_za my mistake. I wasn't trying to just get code but I thought my example was a bit long and not very good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy *regular expression* will do in the *simplest case*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string source = "hello 1234 bye"; 
  string result = Regex.Replace(source, "[0-9]+", "$0,");
```

we are looking for numbers (which are 1 or more digits - `[0-9]+`) and replace entire match `$0` into match with comma: `$0,`.

**Edit:** If you have *several formats* let's combine them with `|`:

```
  string source = "hello 1234 1/2 45-78 bye";

  // hello 1234, 1/2, 45-78, bye
  string result = Regex.Replace(source,
    @"(?:[0-9]+/[0-9]+)|(?:[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)|[0-9]+"
     "$0,");
```

**Edit 2:** if we want to *generalize* (i.e. "other numbers" are any combination of numbers joined with any symbol which is not alphamumeric or white space, e.g. `12;45`, `123.78`, `49?466` etc)

```
  string source = "hello 123 1/2 3-456 7?56 4.89 7;45 bye";

  // hello 123, 1/2, 3-456, 7?56, 4.89, 7;45, bye
  string result = Regex.Replace(source,
    @"(?:[0-9]+[\W-[\s]][0-9]+)|[0-9]+"
     "$0,");
```

Comment: That does not work for "this also 12-3 has numbers" for example.

Comment: @Magnus: you are quite right, thank you! the *regular expression* should be modified if we have several formats

Answer (score 1):

We are going to use regex for this. Here your pattern is number-possible character-number or number:

- `\d+` any number
- `(-|/)?` possible - or /
- `\d+` any number

or

- `\d+` any number

to sum:

```
(\d+(-|/)?\d+)|\d+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-0qfsn81v1MT66Ao)

Now, we use [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) with our pattern.

> #### Regex.Replace
>
> In a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a regular expression pattern with a specified replacement string.

[C# Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sCcIdB):

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(AddComma("a 1 b"));
    Console.WriteLine(AddComma("hello 1234 bye"));
    Console.WriteLine(AddComma("987 middle text 654"));
    Console.WriteLine(AddComma("1/2 is a number containing other characters"));
    Console.WriteLine(AddComma("this also 12-3 has numbers"));
}

public static string AddComma(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d+(-|/)?\d+)|\d+", m => $"{m.Value},");
}
```

output:

```
a 1, b
hello 1234, bye
987, middle text 654,
1/2, is a number containing other characters
this also 12-3, has numbers
```

Any comment is welcome :)

Comment: Counter example: `"a 1 b"` expected: `"a 1, b"` actual: `"a 1 b"` (no comma)

Comment: Technically, there's an (eerie) counter example `a ۱۲۳ b` (persian digits) since `\d` means any *unicode digit*, but I doubt if it's an issue. +1